# Capturing / Logging the "CONNECTION time" (not the timeout)

Tags: entity-framework-core, ado.net

There are hundreds of articles about changing/setting the IDbConnection.ConnectionTimeout

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbconnection.connectiontimeout?view=net-6.0

Is there anyway in Entity Framework Core to "know" (capture/audit) how long the Connection (times) took?
Or events that can "handled" to determine it for myself?

My internet searches/SOF searches produce overloaded and not applicable results because of the ambiguity of the search terms.

I am trying to figure out how long our "healthy" connections are taking..... to work on bug with connection-that-never-occur.......and to figure out a "calculated timeout setting", not a "sounds good" guess.

I am currently on Entity Framework Core "6", by the way.